# How can I embed an interactive webpage in a PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed, acrobat

When making a webpage with HTML, you can use the iframe tag as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://www.website.com" width="800" height="800">
</iframe>
```

And this lets you view and interact with a webpage within a webpage.
Is there some analagous process to do the same with embedding an interactive webpage within a pdf file you open in browser?
I've looked into this problem a bit and believe that using Adobe Acrobat sounds promising. However, I am not sure how to get started with it, or if it is even useful for my problem. The use case for this scenario would simply be an individual clicking on the link to the pdf I create, and the pdf opens in browser with the embedded webpage visible to the individual who can then manipulate elements of the webpage from within the pdf. Is this possible?

I don't know how important this is, but the webpage that I would like to embed into a pdf is built with javascript, html, and react elements. Using iframe on w3schools worked fine for displaying the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Pdf's are created and designed for static content only, so you cant embed an interactive website.
What you could possibly do is create a html conversion of your pdf and use an iframe on it. Or, the other way, create a static pdf with the rendered website and use that in your pdf.

Comment: What does html conversion of a pdf mean? Do you mean code written in html within the pdf code?

Comment: Take a look in here for reference, https://www.pdftohtml.net/. It converts a pdf to html code.